# Cannot open database error every time

Tags: sql-database

I have a local Sitecore 8.2 instance.
Whenever, I browse this instance for the first time in a day or each time I deploy a dll, it throws this error:

> Cannot open database "MySiteSitecore_Web" requested by the login. The
>   login failed. Login failed for user 'sa'.

To fix this, I have to restart the SQL service. I check the databases if they have gone into recovery mode, but they are good. The DB is also installed in my local machine.

Sometimes, I have to also do an `iisreset`, then refresh the page a few times with a gap of a few seconds after each refresh.

Why does this happen every time and how can I resolve this.

**Stack Trace:**

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "MySiteSitecore_Web"
>   requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'sa'.]
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +353
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +118
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) +268
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +315
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +128
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +265    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +133
>
>   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderCommand..ctor(IDbCommand
>   command, DataProviderTransaction transaction, Boolean openConnection)
>   +113    Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.<>c__DisplayClass4.<CreateCommand>b__3()
>   +48    Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute(Func`1 action, Action recover) +293
>   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.<>c__DisplayClass12.b__10()
>   +30    Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute(Func`1 action, Action recover) +293
>
>   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.CreateReader(String sql,
>   Object[] parameters) +281
>
>   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.GetContentLanguages()
>   +189    Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.LoadLanguages() +133
>
>   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.GetLanguages() +49
>
>   Sitecore.Data.SqlServer.SqlServerDataProvider.ExecuteLoadItemDefinitionsSql(String
>   sql, Object[] parameters, SafeDictionary`2 prefetchData) +90
>   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.EnsureInitialPrefetch()
>   +359    Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.GetPrefetchData(ID
>   itemId) +43
>   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.GetItemDefinition(ID
>   itemId, CallContext context) +9
>   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.DataProvider.GetItemDefinition(ID itemID,
>   CallContext context, DataProviderCollection providers) +156
>   Sitecore.Data.DataSource.GetItemInformation(ID itemID) +88
>   Sitecore.Data.DataSource.GetItemData(ID itemID, Language language,
>   Version version) +31
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.GetItemCommand.GetItem(ID , Language
>   , Version , Database ) +113
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.GetItemCommand.Execute(ID , Language
>   , Version , Database ) +496
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataCommands.GetItemCommand.DoExecute() +142
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute() +93
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.GetItem(ID itemId, Language
>   language, Version version, Database database) +295
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.GetItem(ID itemId, Language
>   language, Version version, Database database, SecurityCheck
>   securityCheck) +141
>   Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.ItemProvider.GetItem.GetItemUnderTestProcessor.Process(GetItemArgs
>   args) +185    (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +475
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.GetItem(ID itemId, Language
>   language, Version version, Database database, SecurityCheck
>   securityCheck) +297
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.GetItem(ID itemId, Language
>   language, Version version, Database database) +147
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.GetItem(ID itemId, Language
>   language, Version version, Database database) +154
>   Sitecore.Data.DeviceRecords.DoGetAll() +77
>   Sitecore.Data.DeviceRecords.GetAll() +44
>   Sitecore.Data.Items.DeviceItem.FindBestMatch(Database database,
>   HttpContextBase httpContext) +65
>   Sitecore.Data.Items.DeviceItem.ResolveDevice(Database database,
>   HttpContextBase httpContext) +131
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.DeviceResolver.Process(HttpRequestArgs
>   args) +303    (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +475
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.(Object , EventArgs ) +515
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +142    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +75    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +93

Comment: can you make sure db_owner membership is checked for your user and database?

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat . Which user? System or Sitecore. Also, if it wasn't, it should always throw the error. right?

Comment: SQL user, "sa" in your case I guess.

Comment: Is the database set to Single User Mode?

Comment: Just wonder if your SQL Server service has Start Mode = "Automatic", what could really be an issue after your Windows OS is restarted

Comment: @i123fr3. When I check the services, the MSSQLSERVER service would still be running. I would still stop & start. After a refresh, the instance loads fine.

Comment: See my previous question above and also check the SQL error logs for a more in-depth reason why the login failed

Comment: could you please try https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004061693-MSSQL-sa-user-keeps-getting-locked-Login-failed-for-user-sa-      this resolution.

Comment: Can you login into management studio and open this database with sa credentials present in your connection string? 
If so, do you have in the initialize pipeline any processors that create a connection to the database that could be using a wrong connection string value? Any hardcoded connection strings that are incorrect?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769099/where-are-sql-server-connection-attempts-logged . Worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is happening every time you publish a dll, it does make me feel like publishing ìs overriding your writing permissions to database. Does your .pubxml file contains the following?

```
<IncludeSetACLProviderOnDestination>False</IncludeSetACLProviderOnDestination>
```

Comment: No it is not present in my Visual Studio project's Local.pubxml file

Comment: Can you add and try publishing? it might be the problem

Comment: Did not work. It still shows the same error after publish

Answer (score 0):

From the description above, there is a possibility that you might have set the Maximum number of concurrent connections for your SQL server. And as soon as that limit exceeds, you start getting this issue. And when you restart your SQL Server service or IIS(that shutdown the applications using the connection), the connections are available back in the pool and hence things start to work.

Please check the limit here:
[image]

[image]

I hope this helps.